# What are the advantages of using constexpr instead of consteval function?

Tags: c++, c++20, consteval

This might seem the same question as [What are the advantages of using consteval instead of constexpr function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64741639/what-are-the-advantages-of-using-consteval-instead-of-constexpr-function)
but it is actually exactly the opposite:

Now that we have C++20 consteval, what are the (realistic) scenarios for which I would still need/create a constexpr function instead of consteval a function (or an ordinary function)?

I know that constexpr functions can also be called with parameters evaluated at run time, unlike consteval functions (see *** in the sample code), but why would I ever need that? I mean I can also use an ordinary function then.

```
int FunNormal()
{
    return 12345;
}    

consteval int FunConstEval(int p)
{
    return p+3;
}    

constexpr int FunConstExpr(int p)
{
    return p+3;
}    
    

int main() 
{
    // FunConstEval(FunNormal());               // illegal
    FunConstExpr(FunNormal());                  // legal, but why would I ever want to do this? ***
    
//    constexpr int a1 = FunNormal();           // illegal, obviously
//    constexpr int a1 = FunConstExpr(FunNormal());     // illegal
    constexpr int a2 = FunConstEval(1);     
    constexpr int a3 = FunConstExpr(1);     
}
```

Comment: ".. why would I ever need that?" -> `std::cin >> x; FunContExpr(x);`

Comment: and not all code is written by you. Not all libraries offer their functions as `constexpr` or `consteval`, Sometimes you need to deal with `int FunNormal()` even if in principle all is readily known at compile time

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the question. Are you asking why you would ever need to evaluate something at runtime?

Comment: ".. why would I ever need that?" -> std::cin >> x; FunContExpr(x);
yeah but then I can make that function an ordinary function as well, so why stick to constexpr?

Comment: because an ordinary function cannot produce a `constexpr`. Compare `std::array<int, ordinary_function()>` vs `std::array<int, const_expr_function()>`. A `constexpr` can do both, runtime and compile time.

Answer (score 5):

> ```cpp
> FunConstExpr(FunNormal()); // legal, but why would I ever want to do this?
> ```

`FunNormal` might be a function that obtains its value from user input or another source which isn't available at compile time. As a commenter has pointed out, a `constexpr` function lets you do things like:

```cpp
std::cin >> x;
std::cout << FunConstExpr(x);
```

There is no good reason to artificially restrict your function to *only* run at compile time, unless it is unimplementable at run-time.

`consteval` should only be used for things that *must* be evaluated at compile time. Some examples from the C++ standard library are:

- [`std::source_location::current`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location/current) - The location in the source file cannot be obtained at run-time
- [`std::is_within_lifetime`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_within_lifetime) - The lifetime of objects is only reliably known in constant expressions
- [`std::basic_format_string` constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/basic_format_string) - To type-check the arguments of `std::format`, the format string must be a constant expression

These examples are all fairly rare and unusual. The vast majority of functions should be `constexpr`, not `consteval`.

Comment: I understand that calling a function taking a runtime parameter can't be consteval - (but works with constexpr). But then I can also use an ordinary function.
So my question is why would I make a function constexpr if I sometimes want to call it with runtime parameters. Could make it an ordinary function instead. 
And if I really need compile time evaluation I can use consteval.

Comment: @DanRechtsaf but if you need the same logic (potentially) both in compile and run time (e.g. in different code parts) - why should you have 2 separate functions ? That's what `constexpr` is for.

Comment: I often use `consteval` for helper functions I use inside metaprogramming blocks. The function could be used at runtime but its sole purpose is to be used inside `concept`s, type-traits or other compile time contexts.

Comment: @DanRechtsaf, you'd need 2 distinct functions then; not even 2 overloads, because the inputs would have similar types. `constexpr` keyword allows you to define both functions simultaneously, with same name and signature. You can even devide the implementation with an `if consteval` clause; so that you can provide special optimizations for runtime case.

Answer (score 2):

- `FunNormal()` can only be used at runtime
- `FunConstEval` can only be used at compile time
- `FunConstExpr` might be used in both (compile time in constant expression, else at runtime).

*"Non-constexpr operations"* are forbidden in `consteval`/`constexpr` functions.Those operations depend on standard used.

One additional restriction with `consteval`/`constexpr` functions is that they need to be defined where used (so mostly `inline` in header), whereas, for regular functions, we can separate declaration (header) and definition (source file).

So

- If your function cannot be compile-time, it has to be regular one.
- If your function has to be compile-time only, it has to be `consteval` function.
- If your function has to be both, it has to be `constexpr`.

For other cases, you might choose

- if function is only used in compile time context, `constexpr` or `consteval`.
- if function is only used in runtime time context, `constexpr` or regular one.

For internal/private functions, do as your convenience.
Having `constexpr` for functions only used at runtime is unneeded, but might allow compiler to signal non-constexpr operations inside the function.

Having `consteval` instead of `constexpr` would spot/prevent runtime usage.

For functions in public interface, and for not breaking backward compatibility,
you might turn:

- regular functions into `constexpr` ones.
- `consteval` functions into `constexpr` ones.