MSVC constexpr error "a non-constant (sub-)expression was encountered (with no info) (works on Clang!)
While working on my own array types, I encountered this issue, where one of my unit tests passes for Clang, but fails on MSVC with the following messages:
error C7595: 'UnitTest': call to immediate function is not a constant expression  
note: a non-constant (sub-)expression was encountered  
note: the call stack of the evaluation (the oldest call first) is  
note: while evaluating function 'void UnitTest(void)'  

https://godbolt.org/z/KrbWMe8sM
Code is:
#include <exception>
#include <memory>

template <typename ElementType, size_t ElementCount>
class StaticArray
{

public:

    template <typename OA>
    constexpr StaticArray(OA&& otherArray)
        : m_cxBuffer(std::allocator<ElementType>().allocate(static_cast<size_t>(ElementCount)))
    {
        using OtherArrayType = decltype(otherArray);
        using OtherArrayTypeNoRef = std::remove_reference_t<OtherArrayType>;

        m_count = std::extent_v<OtherArrayTypeNoRef>;

        ElementType* src = otherArray;
        ElementType* srcEnd = src + m_count;
        ElementType* dst = m_cxBuffer;

        ElementType* srcCurrent = src;
        ElementType* dstCurrent = dst;
        while (srcCurrent != srcEnd)
        {
            std::construct_at(dstCurrent, std::move(*srcCurrent));
            ++srcCurrent;
            ++dstCurrent;
        }
    }

    constexpr ~StaticArray() noexcept
    {
        while (m_count > 0)
            std::destroy_at(m_cxBuffer + (--m_count));

        std::allocator<ElementType>().deallocate(m_cxBuffer, static_cast<size_t>(ElementCount));
    }

    size_t m_count = 0;
    ElementType* m_cxBuffer = nullptr;

}; // class StaticArray


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


consteval void UnitTest()
{
    size_t cppArray[] = { 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55 };
    StaticArray<size_t, 15> sArr = std::move(cppArray);  // line 54
}
static_assert((UnitTest(), true), "failed!");

Removing the std::move from line 54 makes it work correctly in this whittled-down example, but is not acceptable for the full version where I want to distinguish between moving and copying.
Is this a bug with MSVC, or is Clang incorrect in accepting this code?

Thanks a lot for providing a link to Godbolt, but please embed everything needed to answer the question into the question's body itself. Links tend to expire.

Note that it's enough to remove all template parameters and fields from StaticArray, as well as the whole implementation of the constructor.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58466245/is-compiler-allowed-to-call-an-immediate-consteval-function-during-runtime

Let's see if I can fit the minimized example ("remove all template parameters and fields from StaticArray, as well as the whole implementation of the constructor") in a comment. If it fits in a comment, it fits in a question, no? `#include 
struct StaticArray
{
template 
constexpr StaticArray(OA&& otherArray) {}
constexpr ~StaticArray() = default;
}; // class StaticArray
consteval void UnitTest()
{
size_t cppArray[] = { 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55 };
StaticArray sArr = std::move(cppArray);
}
static_assert((UnitTest(), true), "failed!");`

Allocate is NOT constexpr : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/allocate. In general dynamic memory allocation and constexpr functions do not mix.

@PepijnKramer The very page you link to says [[nodiscard]] constexpr T* allocate( std::size_t n ); (since C++20)

@n.m.couldbeanAI Oh dear, I totally missed that :(

@JaMiT You can also remove comments, the destructor, and replace the long array of size_t with int arr[] = {1}

Reduced failcase (no includes), so the difference comes from the compilers, not the C++ standard libraries.

@yeputons "You can also remove comments, the destructor, and replace the long array of size_t with [...]" -- I thought I had removed the destructor. Must've hit undo before copying. Oops. The rest I left as an intentional decision. (People often under-comment code, so I I generally leave comments alone unless they become inapplicable. The array fits on one line, so there is minimal gain from reducing it.)

FWIW: I suspect MSVC is wrong, but I don't know. Based on some of the messages it gave me while I was experimenting, it seems to be (not sure) turning the moved reference to the array into a pointer to the array. However, this gets into language details I don't know well. It's a fine enough point that I'm not even sure I trust cppreference.com 100% on this. (The site says a move is "exactly equivalent" to a static_cast to the rvalue reference, but that's not the case for MSVC -- a static_cast works where std::move does not.)
